# Does CakePHP 3.x auth only work with users table?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my database I have the table

```
admins 
  - username
  - password
```

I want to log in users using this table.

When ever I try to login, it gives me an error:

```
sql error: unknown column Users.Username is not found
```

Does CakePHP 3.x Auth only work with an `users` table?

Answer (score 0):

`AuthComponent` lets you specify a different `userModel`. Example:

```
// Pass settings in using 'all'
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Members'],
   'Basic',
   'Form'
]);
```

Please check the docs:

- [Configuring Authentication Handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: `$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ],

                    'userModel' => 'Admins'
                ]
            ]);`

Comment: Thanks for replying...if i have two login one for admins and one for users..do i need to create two separate AppController.php